# Fragment no carga

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un Slide View en `activity_main`, cuando le doy en el menú al fragment para cargar no carga sigue la pantalla de `activity_main`

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    WebView mWebView;

    public BlankFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.es");

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(80);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }    
}
```

Comment: como estas creando ese fragment? haria falta ver el layout y el activity.

Comment: @jorgegarcia, como comenta jirungaray tal vez el problema es al cargar el Fragmente, agregué una respuesta, pero es importante agregues el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat para saber exactamente que problema tienes.

Answer (score 1):

El problema podría no ser en el `Fragment`, probablemente la forma en como cargas el `Fragment` es el problema, esta debe ser la forma correcta:

```
 // Crea el nuevo fragmento y la transacción.
 Fragment nuevoFragmento = new BlankFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento);
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

 // Commit a la transacción
 transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre por que en el `onCreateView` estás inflando al último el layout y llamas abres a las cosas, lo ideal es que crees un método aparte que se llame `onActivityCreated` y dentro de este poner lo que declaraste en el `onCreateView`.

Por que lo primero que debes hacer es inflar la layout con el `onCreateView` y en tu `onCreateActivity` declaras:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.es");

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(80);
```

Cuando llegue a casa te lo estructuro mejor, estoy desde el cel.

Comment: en onCreateActivity() ???  creo que la inicialización es correcta dentro de onCreateView.