# Cambiar de un fragment a otro por medio de un boton

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Lo que trato es pasar de un fragmento a otro cuando se pulsa un botón, el código que estoy utilizando es:

```
public class DimensionFragment extends Fragment {

    Button Bmeters,
           Bfeet;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dimension, container, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dimension, container, false);

            Bmeters = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonmeters);
        Bmeters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                Intent Bmeters = new Intent( getActivity() ,Meters.class);
                startActivity(Bmeters);
            }
        });

        Bfeet=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfeet);

        return view;

    }
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error cuando ejecuto

> 04-26 12:06:04.705
>   3879-3879/com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                Process: com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3, PID: 3879
>                                                                                                android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3/com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3.DimensionFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:932)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1047)
>                                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:940)
>                                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:929)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3.Fragmen2$2.onClick(Fragmen2.java:52)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 6):

Es mejor trabajar con fragments separados.
por ejemplo crear un propio Layout para el fragment
**fragment_meters_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/texto_fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:padding="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

es solo un ejemplo.

Luego declaras una clase que lo controle, como lo estas haciendo en tu otro fragment

**FragmentMeter.java**

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meter_layout, container, false);

    return vista;
}
}
```

el Layout de tu activity debe estar algo asi

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

......

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor">

</RelativeLayout>

....
```

Si tienes tus fragments asi, y tu activity con un layout que contendra los fragments.

Entonces en tu evento click haces lo siguiente:

```
  Bmeters = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonmeters);
    Bmeters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentMeter fr=new FragmentMeter();
            fr.setArguments(bn);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contenedor,fr)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        }
    });
```

desde un fragment se puede acceder a

> getSupportFragmentManager()
>   desde su activity con getActivity()

El activity es quien cambiara el fragment en su interior, por es se deberia llamar al activity del fragment

Comment: yo tengo una duda respecto a Fragments como puedo hacer para que al precionar un radio button me muestre un fragment y al precionar otro radio button me muestre otro fragment!! los codigos de arriba no me funcionaron para pasar de fragment

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal es que no has declarado en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` la `Activity` calculosmatematicos3 que contendría el `Fragment` DimensionFragment :

> **ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class** 
>   {com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3/com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3.DimensionFragment}

---

Veo que también realizas un Intent para abrir `Meters`, de esta forma se abre una Activity pero no se realiza la transacción de un Fragment:

```
 Intent Bmeters = new Intent( getActivity() ,Meters.class);
 startActivity(Bmeters);
```

La forma correcta para cambiar un Fragmento es mediante [**FragmentTransaction**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36713/95):

```
 // Crea el nuevo fragmento y la transacción.
 Fragment nuevoFragmento = new BlankFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento);
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

 // Commit a la transacción
 transaction.commit();
```

Comment: tengo otro error en el codigo se rompe el app .

Comment: transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento); en esa linea remplazo el id por el id del fragmen que quiero pasar  , pero en esta no lo tengo claro Fragment nuevoFragmento = new BlankFragment();

Comment: fragment_container es un frame en tu layout .xml donde se reemplazaran los fragmentos,  Fragment nuevoFragmento es un ejemplo de un Fragment, como se llama el Fragment que intentas cargar?

Comment: fragment_meters ese es el nombre del que intentó cargar cuando presione el botón

Comment: Agrega tus clases y el layout en donde se encuentra el FrameLayout en donde se reemplazara el fragmento.

Comment: `  public void onClick(View v) {

                DimensionFragment dimensionFragment = new DimensionFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmen2, dimensionFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
`

Comment: utilize ese funciona pero el segundo fragmet se posiciona encima del primero

Answer (score -1):

con el botón Bmeters es tratando de cambiar a una Activity no a un Fragment.
Hay 2 tipos de librerías para Fragment:

```
android.app.Fragment
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

El primero es para API de 11 o más, el segundo para API 10 ó menos.
Para la librería `app.Fragment`, importa estas librerías:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

y así se cambia de fragment (`android.app.Fragment`):

```
FragmentMeters fragment = new FragmentMeters();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "fragment_meters");
ft.addToBackStack(null);  //opcional, si quieres agregarlo a la pila
ft.commit();
```

Para la librería `support.v4.app.Fragment`, importa:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Así se cambia de fragment, al hacer click en el botón, del DimensionFragment al FragmentMeters, en caso de que se use la librería `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` :

```
Bmeters = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonmeters);
    Bmeters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           FragmentMeters fragment = new FragmentMeters();
           FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.replace(R.id.frame,  fragment, "fragment_meters");
           ft.addToBackStack(null);
           ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

Dentro de tu layout de la ACTIVITY debes de incluir el Frame Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Por último y si los agregastes a la pila, agrega un color de fondo a los layout de los fragments para que no se vean empalmados, ó agrega:

```
android:background="?android:colorBackground"
```