# Problema para tener dos menús en Android

Tags: android-studio

intento poner un **Menú Lateral** creo que su nombre seria `Navigation Drawer Expandible ListViewm` junto con un **Menú Horizontal** en el `TabLayout`.

He probado a crear los menús por separado y cada uno funciona bien, pero a la hora de juntarlos en el `MainActivity` empiezan los problemas, parece que hay conflicto con en los **import**

Si dejo uno da error el otro, si pongo el import el otro ya no da error, peri el primero, y como no se pueden tener los dos, no sé qué hacer.

Os dejo el código que tengo puesto en el MainActivity para el **Navigation Drawer**, a ver si me podéis decir cómo solucionarlo.

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.A.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView;
import com.A.extras.MenuItem;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu;


private TextView Texto_Titulo;
private Typeface Fuente_kunstler;

private Toolbar toolbar; 
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ExpandableListView mDrawerExpandableList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

private List<String> grupos;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> datosGrupos;
private int ultimaPosicionExpList = -1;
private MyAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //hacer lo que quieras
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });


// -------- 1111 --------------- CODIGO PARA EL MENU LATERAL -----------------------------


    //mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerExpandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explist_slidermenu);
    mDrawerExpandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);//Indicador flecha desplegable izquierda oculta

    //A continuación añadimos cabecera general...
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cabecera_general, null);
    mDrawerExpandableList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    //...y pie de página
    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pie_pagina, null);
    mDrawerExpandableList.addFooterView(footer, null, false);

    cargarDatos();


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true); 
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerExpandableList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    mDrawerExpandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    mDrawerExpandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (ultimaPosicionExpList != -1 && groupPosition != ultimaPosicionExpList) {
                mDrawerExpandableList.collapseGroup(ultimaPosicionExpList);
            }
            ultimaPosicionExpList = groupPosition;
        }
    });
    mDrawerExpandableList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });

    mDrawerExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            int grup_pos = (int)adapter.getGroupId(groupPosition);
            int child_pos = (int)adapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
            if(grup_pos == 0) {
                switch (child_pos) {
                    case 0:

                        displayView( 0 );  //Elc_Elc

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        displayView( 1 );  // Cre_Cre
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(grup_pos == 1) {
                switch (child_pos) {
                    case 0:
                        displayView( 2 );  // San_V
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        displayView( 3 );  // Saaa_Saaa
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        displayView( 4 );  // Eld_Eld
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(grup_pos == 2) {
                switch (child_pos) {
                    case 0:
                        displayView( 5 );  // Monforte PLO
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            //if(grup_pos == 3) {
            //Acciones
            //}
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerExpandableList);
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        displayView(0);
    }


// ---------1111-------------------------------------------------------------------------


    horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    horizontal_menu.addItem("Telefonos", R.drawable.menu1_icon,true);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Navegador GPS", R.drawable.menu2_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 2", R.drawable.menu3_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 3", R.drawable.menu4_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 4", R.drawable.menu5_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 5", R.drawable.menu6_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 6", R.drawable.menu7_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 7", R.drawable.gps3_icon);

    horizontal_menu.showItems();


    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

    horizontal_menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    });

}   //llave que cierra el oncreate



// -------- 2222 --------------- CODIGO PARA EL MENU LATERAL -----------------------------

private void cargarDatos() {

    grupos = new ArrayList<String>();
    datosGrupos = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    grupos.add("Menu Lateral 1");
    grupos.add("Menu Lateral 2");
    grupos.add("Menu Lateral 3");
    //grupos.add("Grupo 4");

    List<String> hijos_grupo1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    hijos_grupo1.add("Elc");
    hijos_grupo1.add("Cre");

    List<String> hijos_grupo2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    hijos_grupo2.add("San V.");
    hijos_grupo2.add("Saaa");
    hijos_grupo2.add("Eld");

    List<String> hijos_grupo3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    hijos_grupo3.add("Mon_PLO");

    //List<String> hijos_grupo4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    //hijos_grupo4.add("Hijo 1 de grupo 4");
    //hijos_grupo4.add("Hijo 2 de grupo 4");
    //hijos_grupo4.add("Hijo 3 de grupo 4");
    //hijos_grupo4.add("Hijo 4 de grupo 4");

    datosGrupos.put(grupos.get(0), hijos_grupo1);
    datosGrupos.put(grupos.get(1), hijos_grupo2);
    datosGrupos.put(grupos.get(2), hijos_grupo3);
    //datosGrupos.put(grupos.get(3), hijos_grupo4);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, grupos, datosGrupos);
    mDrawerExpandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Elc_Elc();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Cre_Cre();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new SanV_SanV();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Saaa_Saaa();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Eld_Eld();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new MoPLO_MoPLO();
            break;
        default:
            //fragment = new Elc_Elc();
            break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


// ---------2222-------------------------------------------------------------------------


//crea el menu de opciones en el Toolbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_opciones, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:  
            onBackPressed();     
            return true;         

        case R.id.m_acerca:
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            Typeface t = Typeface.create("serif", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            tv.setTypeface(t);
            tv.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            TextView versionname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ver_name);
            tv.setText("version : " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
            toast.setView(tv);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return true;

        case R.id.m_salir:
            //finish();
            onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_stop_1);
        builder.setMessage("Quieres salir de la aplicación?");
        builder.setTitle("Cerrar xxxx");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }



private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Telefonos();
            case 1:
                return new Navegador_GPS();
            case 2:
                return new Menu_2();
            case 3:
                return new Menu_3();
            case 4:
                return new Menu_4();
            case 5:
                return new Menu_5();
            case 6:
                return new Menu_6();
            case 7:
                return new Menu_7();
            default:
                return new Telefonos();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 8;
    }

}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.FondoMenu"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <com.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundMenuColor="#0099cc"
        app:backgroundNotifications="@color/colorAccent"
        app:icon_height="30dp"
        app:icon_width="30dp"
        app:item_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:item_colorSelected="#ffffff"
        app:item_textColor="#ffffff" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ver_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/explist_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#A4C739"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:listSelector="#bfbfbf"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**HorizontalScrollMenuView.xml**

```
public class HorizontalScrollMenuView extends LinearLayout {

private AppCompatActivity context;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
private ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();

private int itemSeletected = 0;


//attrs
private int icon_width = 20;
private int icon_height = 20;
private int backgroundMenuColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
private int backgroundNotifications = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
private int item_textColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");
private int item_backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
private int item_marginTop = 0;
private int item_marginBottom = 0;
private int item_marginLeft = 0;
private int item_marginRight = 0;
private int item_colorSelected = Color.parseColor("#0099cc");
private int item_textSize = 16;

public HorizontalScrollMenuView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = (AppCompatActivity) context;
    init();
}

public HorizontalScrollMenuView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = (AppCompatActivity) context;


    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView, 0, 0);
    icon_height = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_icon_height, 20);
    icon_width = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_icon_width, 20);
    backgroundMenuColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_backgroundMenuColor, backgroundMenuColor);
    backgroundNotifications = a.getColor(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_backgroundNotifications, backgroundNotifications);
    item_textColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_textColor, item_textColor);
    item_backgroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_backgroundColor, item_backgroundColor);
    item_colorSelected = a.getColor(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_colorSelected, item_colorSelected);
    item_marginTop = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_marginTop, 0);
    item_marginBottom = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_marginBottom, 0);
    item_marginLeft = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_marginLeft, 0);
    item_marginRight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_marginRight, 0);
    item_textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.HorizontalScrollMenuView_item_textSize, 16);

    a.recycle();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.hscroll_menu, this, true);

    init();

}

private void init() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(context, menuItems, icon_width, icon_height, item_textColor,
            item_backgroundColor, item_marginTop, item_marginBottom, item_marginLeft,
            item_marginRight, item_colorSelected, item_textSize, backgroundNotifications);

    itemAdapter.setOnHSItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnHSItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHSClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
            onHSMenuClickListener.onHSMClick(menuItem, position);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundMenuColor);
}

/**
 * agrega un nuevo item al menu
 *
 * @param text texto del item
 * @param icon icono para el item
 */
public void addItem(String text, int icon) {
    menuItems.add(new MenuItem(icon, text));
}

/**
 * agrega un nuevo item al menu, pero este se mostrara como seleccionado
 *
 * @param text    texto del item
 * @param icon    icono para el item
 * @param seleted
 */
public void addItem(String text, int icon, boolean seleted) {
    menuItems.add(new MenuItem(icon, text, seleted));
}


/**
 * agrega un nuevo item al menu, pero este se mostrara como seleccionado
 *
 * @param text    texto del item
 * @param icon    icono para el item
 * @param seleted
 */
public void addItem(String text, int icon, boolean seleted, int numNotifications) {
    menuItems.add(new MenuItem(icon, text, seleted));
    menuItems.get(menuItems.size() - 1).setNumNotifications(numNotifications);
    menuItems.get(menuItems.size() - 1).setNotifications(true);
}


/**
 * agrega un nuevo item al menu, pero este se mostrara como seleccionado
 *
 * @param text texto del item
 */
public void addItem(String text, int icon, int numNotifications) {
    menuItems.get(menuItems.size() - 1).setNumNotifications(numNotifications);
    menuItems.get(menuItems.size() - 1).setNotifications(true);
}

/**
 * @return retorna  la posicion del item seleccionado en el menu
 */
public int getItemSeletected() {
    return itemSeletected;
}


/**
 * edita un item del menu
 * @param position          posicion del item en el menu
 * @param text              nuevo texto para el item
 * @param icon              nuevo icono para el item
 * @param showNotifications true o false para decidir si se muestra el badge de notificaciones
 * @param numNotifications  numero de notificaciones en el badge
 */
public void editItem(int position, String text, int icon, boolean showNotifications, int numNotifications) {
    menuItems.get(position).setNumNotifications(numNotifications);
    menuItems.get(position).setNotifications(showNotifications);
    menuItems.get(position).setIcon(icon);
    menuItems.get(position).setText(text);

    itemAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


/**
 * muestra todos los items del menu
 */
public void showItems() {
    itemAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, menuItems.size() - 1);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


/**
 * cambia el estado de un item a seleccionado
 *
 * @param position posicion del item en el menu
 */
public void setItemSelected(int position) {
    if (menuItems.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.size(); i++) {
            if (i == position)
                menuItems.get(i).setSelected(true);
            else
                menuItems.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }
        itemAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, menuItems.size() - 1);
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
        itemSeletected = position;
    }
}


/**
 * @return retorna el numero de items que tiene el menu
 */
public int numItems() {
    return menuItems.size();
}


/**
 * retorna un item del menu
 *
 * @param position posicion del item en el menu (desde 0)
 * @return
 */
public MenuItem getItem(int position) {
    return menuItems.get(position);
}


public interface OnHSMenuClickListener {
    /**
     * para capturar los eventos cuando se da click sobre un item del menu
     *
     * @param menuItem item seleccionado
     * @param position posicion del item en el menu (iniciando desde 0)
     */
    void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position);
}


private OnHSMenuClickListener onHSMenuClickListener;

public void setOnHSMenuClickListener(OnHSMenuClickListener onHSMenuClickListener) {
    this.onHSMenuClickListener = onHSMenuClickListener;
}
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar uno de los fragmentos que estas instanciando.

Comment: @David ya esta solucionado en parte, al copiar las clases Fragmen, el error que se muestra en los `fragment = new Elc()` estaba en esas clases Fragmen, se cambio la clase a `public class Eld extends android.app.Fragment` no se porque pero metio por medio el **android.app**.Fragment ahora el problema que me esta dando es que al pulsar el icono del Toolbar para mostrar el Menu Lateral, se cambia el icono por el de la flecha, pero no muestra el contenido del ´Navigation Drawer´ he puesto arriba el codigo que tengo en **activity_main.xml** por si puede estar ahí el problema y quieres comentar algo

Comment: cual es el fragment que contiene los tabs(viewpager)?

Comment: Hola @armen, a ver si he acertado con el codigo, ya que ese codigo esta en otro modulo java http://funkyimg.com/i/2DUDz.png lo he puesto en el primer post y he eliminado las fotos para que no sea muy extenso

Comment: es solo una Activity? si así es, uno de los fragments del Nav Drawer debe contener los tabLayout

Comment: Si solo hay una Activity, he editado el **activity_main.xml** del primer post, ahora si muestra los dos menús, pero solo funcionan las opciones del menú horizontal, el menú lateral se muestra, pero luego al pulsar sobre uno de sus apartados no muestran el contenido, no sé si es en el activity_main.xml donde tengo que cambiar lo que dices, no tengo muy claro cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Primero tienes que ver que estás utilizando diferentes clases `Fragment`, una es de la biblioteca de compatibilidad y la otra no. Por otro lado el tema de que te sale la flecha en la `ActionBar` es por la llamada a este método `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Pero ahora los menús ya se muestran bien, y al pulsar en los botones/opciones que tienen los menús, ya asea el horizontal o lateral, el contenido que muestran son de clases Fragment que son iguales, y como comentas lo las librerías diferentes, he visto un comentario de @armen sobre librerías diferentes https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137666/69037 que no se si tiene que ver algo con lo que comentas, y si hay alguna forma de solucionarlo, y otro comentario aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154113/9215136 que si ya en español me cuesta entenderlo, en ingles mucho menos :(

Comment: @armen, creo que estoy quemando ya los últimos cartuchos antes de abandonar, estoy probando otro proyecto en el que el menú horizontal esta en `ArrayList`, pero me estoy encontrando en la misma situación, siguiendo con este código, como puedo hacer lo que dices de... **poner uno de los fragments del Nav Drawer debe contener los tabLayout ?**

Comment: cada uno de los fragmentos del NavDrawer (Elc, Cre, San_V ...) van a  tener los TabLayout (Telefonos, Navegador_GPS ...)? y cual va contener al HorizontalScrollMenuView?

Comment: Hola, el menu horizontal esta en el TabLayout que tiene los botones/opciones (Telefonos, Navegador, etc..) y los que estan en el menu Lateral, tiene (Elc, Cre, etc..), mira esta video, se ve mejor los menus como estan y como se ven en la aplicación, y como no muestra el contenido del menu Lateral, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtbckGC42DE

Comment: Entonces @armen se puede hacer algo, no te lo pregunto para meter prisa, si no que al no comentar nada, no se si me vas a poder ayudar, o has visto que no se puede hacer.

Comment: el video no existe. Pondré un ejemplo de Nav Drawer con tabs

Comment: lo pongo otra vez, lo quite porque he visto que nadieo lo reproducia, yo lo puedes ver, estoy probanco con otros codigos que voy viendo, y no se si el problema esta en el orden del activity_main.xml

Comment: pues los que te pregunté, que item del menu lateral contendrá los tabs? Te dejo un ejemplo

Comment: Pero el menu horizontal no esta, o no se muestra en uno de los fragment del menu lateral, son menus independientes, estan puestos en el activity principal, y desde ahi muestro los dos menus,

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que quieres tener un Nav Drawer, con una sola activity, con 3 fragments (Fragment1, 
Fragment2 y Fragment 3) y en el Fragment1 quieres un tabLayout que contenga 3
fragments(Fragment1a, Fragment1b, Fragment1c). Los layout se forman así:

En el activity_main.xml agregas el Drawer Layout que incluya el ActionBar(Toolbar). Aquí el NavigationView
incluye el menu del drawer (activity_main_drawer), este debe estar en res-menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

El app_bar_main.xml contiene el toolbar e incluye el content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ejemplo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

El content_main.xml contiene el FrameLayout, que es donde se mostrarán los fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ejemplo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y este es un ejemplo del menu activity_main-drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_uno"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Inicio" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dos"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Dos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tres"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Tres" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

El fragment1.xml es el que va contener los Tabs y el ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ejemplo de fragment2.xml, e igual para el 3, estos no contienen tabs, solo vistas.Igual estos podrían ser
los fragments1a, 1b y 1c:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="FRAGMENTO 2"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

En java el MainActivity sería así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

           //puedes iniciar la app con cualquier fragment, en este caso inicia con
           //el Fragment1a que es el primer tab del Fragment1:
            Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.frame, fragment, "iniciofragment");
            ft.commit();


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

         if (id == R.id.nav_uno) {
            Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "iniciofragment");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_dos) {
            Fragment2 fragment = new FragmentInicio();
            ......
    }
```

Ahora bien, el Fragment1.java es el que contendrá los tabs:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static TabLayout fragTabs;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3;
    public static String CURRENT_POSITION_KEY;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,null);
        fragTabs = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        //para que funcione el setupWithViewPager se requiere de este runnable
        fragTabs.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fragTabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
        return x;

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int currentPos = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_POSITION_KEY);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPos);
        }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CURRENT_POSITION_KEY, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    //En la clase Adapter es mejor usar FragmentStatePagerAdapter que FragmentPagerAdapter, 
    //pues así se utiliza menos memoria
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        //la posicion de cada fragment:
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new Fragment1a();
                case 1 : return new Fragment1b();
                case 2 : return new Fragment1c();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return int_items;
        }

        //agrega los títulos a la pestaña de acuerdo a la posición:
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "uno A";
                case 1 :
                    return "Uno B";
                case 2 :
                    return "Uno C";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso utilizé las librerías de support fragment, ya que se requieren éstas para poder utilizar los child fragments en el viewpager:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: Gracias @armen pero creo que como te comentaba en el último mensaje antes de colocar este código, no están creados así los menús, el menú horizontal no está en el primer Fragmen del menú lateral, los menús siempre están a la vista, si muestras el fragment 2 del menú lateral, desaparece el menú horizontal, te dejo el código completo del activity en el primer post, en un principio solo tenía el menú horizontal "HorizontalScrollMenu" y a partir de este, en el Toolbar añadí el botón para mostrar el menú lateral, son independientes uno de otro.

Comment: el FrameLayout debe ir fuera del DrawerLayout. Básate en el ejemplo. No veo donde agregas los fragments del NavDrawer al frame_container (FrameLayout)

Comment: Hola @armen, como te comentaba en el primer post te puse el código completo del **MainActivity.java** ahí puedes ver los `import` de las librerías que utilizo, y en el **activity_main.xml** faltaba parte del código, lo he puesto completo, y he dejado el `<FrameLayout>` fuera del `<DrawerLayout>`, a ver si es así como dices, aunque por desgracia sigo sin mostrar los fragmen del menú lateral, también puedes ver en el **MainActivity.java** donde tengo el código para llamar a los Fragment del menú lateral, que está en el ` `private void displayView(int position)`